# ClearCase time and query

Tags: clearcase, config-spec

This config-spec show the files I need:

```
element -dir * '{version(/main/LATEST) && !version(SLT-T)}'
element -file * '{version(/main/LATEST) && !version(SLT)}'
```

Now I need to see how the source looked at some point in the future, so I do this:

```
time 01-Nov-2008
element -dir * '{version(/main/LATEST) && !version(SLT-T)}'
element -file * '{version(/main/LATEST) && !version(SLT)}'
```

Unfortunately this still shows me "the present". The manual says:

> Time rules may be nested. They may not include any query language constructs.

Okay, but what do I do then?

How do I exclude files and directories with a certain label, without using query language? Or is there way to specify time in the query language?

(No files has a SLT-T label, and no directories has a SLT label.)

Comment: If you can edit your question and add some precision illustrating why your config spec does not allow you to see where your label was, I will be able to add further suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try adding some query-language directives like:

```
&& !ver{created_since(1-Nov-2008)}
&& ver{created_since(1-Nov-2008)}
```

(all the versions existing before/after 1 Nov. 2008)

That is part of the query language and may help you refining your selection rules.

---

I confirm for having tested it:

```
element /myPath/... /main/{!created_since(01-Sep-2008)}
element /myPath/... /main/LATEST
```

would give you all version created before September the first in this instance.

I am not sure it can be combined with your rules to successfully achieve what you are looking for, though.

My point was just to make sure you can include time-based selection rules in your config spec.

Comment: I don't think this will work.
Imagine a file created in January, end changed in March. If I say {!created_since(Feb)}, I will se the March-version, but I need the January-version.

Comment: Hmmm... {!created_since(Feb)} would give you the January version, not the March one.

Comment: I checked the manual, but apparantly I misunderstood it. This is probably what I was searching for.
My next problem is that I cannot see where labels was in the past. But I think that is just something I will have to live with.