# how to find out all the activities happend in a branch in the last month?

Tags: clearcase

My problem is that The code in the branch I'm working in for some reason is corrupted now , but I didn't make any label in the branch so It's hard to "roll back" the code to a valid status.

But I'm sure a month ago  the code is in the quite healthy status , so I'd like to know all the activities happen in the branch in the last month then I can manully roll back each activity .

So As title, could any one of you tell me how to list all the activities happend in a branch in the last month ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What source control system do you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not forget the time directive of selection rule.

```
element /myPath/... /main/{!created_since(16-Sep-2009)}
element /myPath/... /main/LATEST
```

Can enable you to see versions from a month ago (see [time and query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368086/clearcase-time-and-query))

See also ["time-based rule" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634509/clearcase-loading-older-version-of-a-specific-directory).

From there you can branch and update your code from this older stable point.

Comment: this one was a lifesaver for our TeamCity clearcase plugin :-)

Answer (score 2):

The "lshistory" command can be used to see the list of events that were performed (create version, create branch, etc).

```
ct lshistory -since 16-Sep-2009 -branch your_branch -recurse /path/to/vob
```

This would show all events that happened in /path/to/vob and all files and directories under that happened on your_branch since September 16th, 2009.

Adding "-short" will show the output as a list of elements and their version extended pathname, without the comments and other information.