# Continuous Integration with Teamcity and Clearcase

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, teamcity, clearcase

Has anybody successfully integrated Clearcase with Teamcity (which advertises Clearcase support) to realize a productive continuous integration build environment on a decent size project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes we have, but with a **custom ClearCase plugin for TeamCity**, in order to::

- use a dynamic view set with a **["time" directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577980/how-to-find-out-all-the-activities-happend-in-a-branch-in-the-last-month/1578508#1578508)**, and to
- avoid hundreds of "`descr -l`" for each changed files (which would be Sparta, err, [no, madness, would be madness](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDRAhiBtOrQ&hl=fr) since it would represents hundreds of transaction to the ClearCase server)

Check out the **[TCCC plugin](http://github.com/gphilipp/TCCC)** on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks!  This looks great, I will definitely give it a shot.

Comment: VonC, there's a C missing :-)