# How do I get ClearCase to make an archive of a subdir of snapshot as it was at an earlier revision?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I'm not particularly experienced with ClearCase, so if my terminology is incorrect please let me know.

In Git I can run the command:

```
git archive -o /tmp/dump.zip $SHA_FROM_THE_PAST path/to/dump
```

I want to do something similar in ClearCase.

The ClearCase repository contains two branches: `main` and `snapshot_foo`.
`snapshot_foo` branches from `main` at some point in the past.
What I want is a dump of all the files as they looked at the time the snapshot was first created.

I understand that there is no 'global' state identifier like there is in Git; in AFAIK, in ClearCase each element is versioned individually, so there will not necessarily be a one-to-one equivalent to that command.

I've thought about creating a new snapshot starting at the same point in time from main, and just copying what I need from that, but I am bewildered and confused as to how I would go about it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest case would be when you have set a label on main just before creating snapshot.

But if you have no such label, you can get all the files at the time just before the creation of the snapshot_foo branch:

- a/ `cleartool descr -l brtype:snapshot_foo@/myVob` to get the date of creation for this branch
- b/ make a snapshot view with a time-based selection rule [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577980/how-to-find-out-all-the-activities-happend-in-a-branch-in-the-last-month/1578508#1578508)

```
    element /myPath/... /main/{!created_since(01-Sep-2008.12:34:56)}
    element /myPath/... /main/LATEST
```

(with 12h 34 minutes 56 seconds being the time just *before* the creation of the brtype `snapshot_foo`)

(see the [`config_spec` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm))

Once the snapshot view is created with the right versions in it, you can zip its content, achieving a similar result to the `git archive` you mention in your question.