# Best way to roll back to previous versions without baseline in CC

Tags: merge, clearcase, rollback

I need to roll back to a previous version of my project, but I haven't really been creating baselines. Whats the best way to do this. I think I have a large clearfsimport operation that marks the current version that my desired view would pre-date.

What is the best way to create a view like this. I was hoping I could do something based on date that would just create a view that includes all versions from Date X and before, or perhaps Activity X and before.

I do have a large number of files that were added and changed and moved so I need something that will exclude all new additions and include all deletions since the target date.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a non-UCM view in which you can specify a **[time directive of selection rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577980/how-to-find-out-all-the-activities-happend-in-a-branch-in-the-last-month/1578508#1578508)**:
see "[ClearCase : Loading Older Version of a specific Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/635282/6309)".

Once you have a view with the right content, you can use it as a source for a `clearfsimport -rmname`, using your UCM view as destination (see [clearfsimport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138321/how-can-i-use-clearcase-to-add-to-source-control-recursively/144310#144310), except here the `-rmname` option make sure you get back the exact same number of files in the destination than selected in your source view).