# View history for list of elements in ClearCase

Tags: view, timestamp, history, clearcase

I'm novice to ClearCase, and recently I merged list of files from branch `A` to branch `B`.
At that time I checked preserved the time stamp option for every files that I merged.

Now, Client needs to review that one it seems, so they are asking for snapshot for every file with its "**created time stamp**" and its "**modified time stamp**" as a list.

I tried using **History** option, but I did not get the **Created date time stamp**.
How can I get that timestamp information?

Answer (score 1):

One way to review those files is to select them into a view:
You can try a view with a time-based selection rule in its config spec.
I would recommend a dynamic view (that way, you can quickly modify the config spec and do multiple tries in order to select the right versions)

See "[how to find out all the activities happened in a branch in the last month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577980/how-to-find-out-all-the-activities-happend-in-a-branch-in-the-last-month)" for an example or such a config spec.

---

But if you are after a list of files, as selected by a view, but with the "modified date" *as well as* the "**creation date**", then a simple `cleartool find`, using [fmt_ccase syntax](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm), is enough:

This will give you all the creation dates:

```
ct find . -type f -exec "cleartool descr -fmt \"%n %e:%d\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%@@\""
```

This will give you all the last modification dates:

```
ct find . -type f -exec "cleartool descr -fmt \"%n %e:%d\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

The only difference is in the '`@@`', which in one case is for referencing the element itself (which has a creation date), and in the other (no '`@@`'), is for referencing the version (which represent the last modification date).

Comment: Thanks pal, please help me with this, i have another doubt in 
[merging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088657/merge-file-from-one-barnch-to-another-branch-in-clearcase)