# Merge file from one barnch to another branch in Clearcase

Tags: view, merge, timestamp, clearcase, preserve

I want to merge a file from one branch to another branch in clearcase,
for example from `Offshore` branch to `DEV` branch.

I want to merge the file with its modification time as it is.

If the modification date of a file (`example.asp`) is `12-02-2011`, after merging the file in `DEV` branch, the modification time for the file (`example.asp`) in `DEV` branch should hold the same modification time (`12-02-2011`).

Which view should I take?
how should I do merge?

**Note:** I tried ***preserve modification time*** option while checkin and checkout during merging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view is easy: when merging, always do so in the destination view, ie in the view which contains the destination version of your merge.

From there, you can display the version tree of that file, and look for the "source version" (the one from which you want to merge, in your case, the one on Offshore branch).

You can right click on the source version and select "Merge to", and then the destination version (the one designated by an "eye").
ClearCase will ask you if you want to checkout that file (say yes) and will perform the merge (but will not checkin the file).

You can then check if the "preserve modification time" applies in your case.

Comment: Yeah i done the way what you have said, but the modification time in offshore branch is actual modified date.But in DEV branch the modification date is changed to checked in date though i tried using preserve modification time option. now what should i do?

Comment: @rk_sweetrascal I think if is possible the only timestamp you might preserve is the destination version one, not the source. And you cannot easily change the timestamp of a checked-in version (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=40676 and http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=255672).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here what i want is, I'm merging a file from one branch with preserve file modification, the same modification time should displayed with the file in destination branch? make sense? why the destination file has checked in date even i preserve file modification option in it?

Comment: @rk_sweetrascal I understand what you want, but I don't think it is possible, because the only timestamp that will be preserved is the one of the *destination* version, not the source version. You checkout and checkin (and preserve the timestamp of) the *destination* version, in the *destination* view.

Comment: @VconC -  is there anyother way i can achieve that one?

Comment: @rk_sweetrascal not that I know of: timestamps aren't easily modifiable. In version control in general, it is best to not to rely too heavily on timestamp.

Comment: VonC - Yeah i thought the same, but my manager asking to do that. 'coz modified time is more important it seems. I should not say that i cant. this is where i'm lagging

Comment: @rk_sweetrascal then you need to register some timestamp in a custom attributes after merging, and use that information later on checkout. But that involves more scripting, and I don't have an implementation ready.