# How to find all files that were changed at last session, or at a given date

Tags: clearcase-remote-client

I'm trying to implement ClearCase at our small site.
We are using CCRC (remote client) only, since we are located away from the CC server.
Now I'm able to check out, change files and then check in a bunch of different files.

However, say at the end of the day, or next day, I want to know which files I modified (or evey a month from now), I'd like to know which files I modified last time I worked on that project.

How could I do that?
Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a (preferably) dynamic view with a time-based selection rule in its config spec.
In your case, ie CCRC, a simple web view will work. Simply limit at first the loading rules, while you experimenting with those special selection rules.

You can see an example of such a rule at [how to find out all the activities happend in a branch in the last month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577980/how-to-find-out-all-the-activities-happend-in-a-branch-in-the-last-month/1578508#1578508)

Comment: Excellent!  That's the solution I was looking for.  Thank you very much.