# ClearCase Command to get older version of commited jars?

Tags: clearcase

I am building a jar on my unix server using clearcase , Now I want to see, the last jar i.e jar without my update . Can I do that in clearcase if yes can someone suggest what is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClearCase only allows you to access the sources from which you are building your jar.

You can create a second view which you can configure to see a tag representing your sources *before* your modifications, assuming you did put a label on your sources before modifying them.

```
 element * CHECKEDOUT
 element * yourLabel
 element * /main/LATEST
```

Even if you didn't put a label, you can still set a **[time-based selection rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/370008/6309)**.