# version selection based on creation date

Tags: clearcase

I would like to select the LATEST version of all elements in a directory based on the creation date otherwise select version 0. Does any one know if this can be achieved using the available config_spec syntax?

eg:

```
if (created_on >= 01-jan-2014)
 element * /main/LATEST
else
 element * /main/0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the hint VonC, I have achieved exactly what I need based on the following rules.

```
element -dir /myPath/... /main/LATEST
element /myPath/... /main/{created_since(01-Jan-2014)}
element /myPath/... /main/0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a time directive of selection rule.

```
element /myPath/... /main/{created_since(01-Jan-2014)}
element /myPath/... /main/LATEST
```

That could enable you to see versions based on their creation date (see [time and query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368086/clearcase-time-and-query))

See also ["time-based rule" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634509/clearcase-loading-older-version-of-a-specific-directory).

The second rule selection LATEST, not 0, as a way to test the first rule: remember that if a parent folder was not selected by the first rule, none of its sub-elements would be considered if it was in version 0.